# WordPress - get_post_type_archive_link with pagination

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I'm building a WordPress website, with a video custom post type. All videos are displayed on a paginated archive page, and open in a modal when clicked.

Because the site search returns single video posts in search results, I've added a function to redirect to the archive page when the single is accessed. I also append the post ID to the URL, and in the archive page I have code that checks for a 'show' parameter to trigger the modal to open:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'custom_post_single_redirect_management' );
function custom_post_single_redirect_management() {
    global $post;
    if(is_singular( 'video' )) {
        wp_redirect( get_post_type_archive_link('video').'?show='.$post->ID, 301 );
        exit;
    }
}
```

So far so good, and all is working fine.

The problem I now have, and I'm hoping you can help with, is when the video being accessed isn't on page 1, I can't open the modal to show the video.

Does anyone have a suggestion for handling this? Is it possible from within my function above, to check which page the video will be on within the archive page, and then add a new parameter on the redirect? i.e. `'?show='.$post->ID.'&page=2'`

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if I'm committing a faux pas by answering my own question, but perhaps it will help others who stumble upon this question.

I could not find an easy way to find the pagination number.  Instead I used [pre_get_post()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) in my functions.php to check for the 'show' parameter, and if it was being passed to the page, I used [stick_post()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/stick_post) to make the post ID passed in the 'show' parameter sticky.

In order to get my custom post type archive to show the sticky, I used [this snippet](http://tareq.wedevs.com/2013/01/sticky-posts-in-custom-post-type-archives/).  Lastly I used [unstick_post()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/unstick_post/) in my template to remove the 'stickiness'.

Altogether this brought the post in question to page 1 in my archive, which then opened in the modal. A bit hacky, but it works.

If there's a better way to achieve this please post it and I'll accept your answer as best.